# Selenium fails to open page on localhost

Tags: tomcat, testing, selenium

I have a Tomcat server running at localhost:8000 with a deployed web application at localhost:8000/selenium_demo/. The application is fully functioning and can be normally accessed via browser.

I'm trying to run a selenium test on the app like this:

```
browser = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://localhost:8000");
browser.start();
browser.open("/selenium_demo/");
System.out.println(browser.getBodyText());
```

But at the call of `browser.open(...)` I always get a timeout exception. I tried to set the waiting time to 60s with the same result.

If I call `browser.open("/")` I'm able to get the Tomcat default homepage, but every other address fails. What could be the problem? I'm running all this on a Debian machine.

Comment: Looks like a pathing problem. Where's the script in relation to `selenium_demo`?

Comment: The script is at `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/selenium_demo/src/test/java/com/jardo/selenium_demo` and the webapp is in the Tomcat directory: `/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/selenium_demo`. But what has this to do with paths?

Comment: Have you tried the same using WebDriver script?

Comment: I tried replacing `new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://localhost:8000");` with `new WebDriverBackedSelenium(new FirefoxDriver(), "http://localhost:8000");` and got the following error: `org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host localhost on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output: Error: no display specified`. I don't quite understand this. Why is Firefox trying to connect to port 7055? The "no display specified" error may have something to do with the fact that I need to run Firefox on a headless server using Xvfb.

Comment: Update the Firefox to versions like 26 and see what happens... if it doesn't work, then check if there is any other session on specific port you are running

Comment: I tried downgrading Selenium to 2.27.0 to match my Firefox 17 (latest Iceweasel), and then I installed Firefox 27 and changed Selenium back to 2.39.0 and I always got the same result. There should not be any other instance that would already block port 7055, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I also tried Firefox 26 and it also failed. But I found out that with Firefox 26 and 27 I'm able to load the page in the original way (without WebDriver). Although it says that javascrit is turned off (which is a problem), its better than nothing.